# Internal representations on CAS calculators

Tags: taylor-expansion, computer-algebra-systems

I’m trying to understand what is going on with CAS calculators when they give warnings like the one in the screenshot from an HP Prime when certain operations are attempted.  I’ve owned other CAS calculators that display similar error messages.  Is it to do with the taylor series being used in most functions or the binary representations and the way integers are handled?  The screenshot is from an iPad however the warning also appears on the hardware version.  I’ve also posted a picture of an evaluation returning true and false, depending on the function called.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you evoke Taylor representation ? For me, the LHS and RHS, **being identical** have the same internal representation, something like "power$(x,-\tfrac12)$"

Comment: Hello Marie and thanks for replying to this post.  The reason I (i think you mean to say “invoked”) the Taylor Series is that I am only a novice in your field and know only a little.  What little I know about how calculators work is that functions are often performed using The Calculus, in particular Taylor Series.  I was merely speculating in the hope some kind soul would point me in the right direction to find an answer.

Comment: CAS are a world in themselves. The equality and the identity of expressions are not the same thing. For example, if your CAS has not been taught that $e^{i \pi}$ is exactly $-1$, it will consider them as 2 different "beings"...

Comment: If you have the opportunity to learn Prolog or LISP computer languages, you will understand a lot about CAS...